# Radius of convergence of a series (text problem)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

the series:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ where $(a_n)_n$ is a limited sequence with $L((a_n)_n) \subseteq \mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$

My main problem is to get to something to work with. I dont know how to transform the sentence to a mathematical expression or something that i can use the usual tools to determine the radius of convergence.

Comment: What is $L((a_n)_n)$?

Comment: the set of limit points of $a_n$

Comment: What about Cauchy-Haddamard formula for hte convergence radius? Or the ratio (quotient) test? Anyway, it will be a very general result as almost nothing is given...

Comment: So in other words, you have $0 < \varepsilon < \lvert a_n\rvert < R$ for some $\varepsilon$, except maybe for finitely many $n$.

Answer (score 0):

So you are supposing that
$$
\liminf_{n\to \infty} |a_n| = \varepsilon > 0.
$$
Hence you have
$$
 \liminf_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|\cdot |x|^n} \ge |x|
$$
which means that when $|x|>1$ the series does not converge.